# How can I inject a generic parameter using Guice?

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, guice

I found other related questions, but none so straightforward:

How can I bind the following generic parameter using Guice?

```
class A<T> {
   T a;
   @Inject A(T a) {
      this.a=a;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class TestGenericBinding {
   static class A<T> {
      T a;
      @Inject A(T a) {
         this.a=a;
      }
   }

    @Test public void bindingWorked() {
       Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

         @Override
         protected void configure() {
            bind(Integer.class).toInstance(123);
            bind(new TypeLiteral<A<Integer>>() {});
         }
      });
       A<Integer> a = injector.getInstance(
          Key.get(new TypeLiteral<A<Integer>>(){}));
       assertEquals(new Integer(123),a.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MairbekKhadikov, I plan to do so, thanks, but SO doesn't let you accept your own answer for 24 hours.